# Is it a bad idea to use steel wall shelf brackets in bathrooms?

Tags: shelving

I'm replacing some wonky floating shelves in the bathroom.  [I've previously used this kind of steel wall shelf bracket](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Heavy-Shelf-Brackets-Scaffold-Shelving/dp/B0B46HLW6N/ref=asc_df_B08MNF9C4W/?tag=googshopuk-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=499353943587&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=16538647456020336220&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9044909&hvtargid=pla-1211636655359&th=1), but is it a bad idea to put steel brackets in a bathroom that's regularly used for showers and gets steamy?

Sorry if that's an obvious question.

Answer (score 3):

**It depends almost entirely on the finish**. I can't find anything about that on the product page, which raises flags for me.

A high quality baked-on enamel or powder coat would probably hold up well. A simple spray finish may begin to blister and rust on the corners within a short time.

Answer (score 1):

These will work great in a bathroom. The site even shows them installed in a bathroom over a tub/shower (not that you can believe everything you see on the web). You'll want to be selective with the material of the shelving though--no particle board, etc. I used tempered glass for mine for easy cleaning.

If the screw color doesn't match the bracket, get some matching acrylic nail polish and touch up the screws. Use it to repair any scratches that might develop.